# How to prevent node.js exec from caching result?

Tags: node.js, shell, exec

I am trying to get WiFi networks list with node.js exec with this code:

```
exec('iwlist ra0 scan | grep ESSID', function(err, out, code) {
    console.log(out);
});
```

It prints all found ESSIDs correnctly. But when I rename my router's ESSID I still get old ESSID no matter how long I wait or how many times I run the code. If I run the same command `iwlist ra0 scan | grep ESSID` from linux shell, I'm getting new ESSID and it also updates in node.js exec results. Looks like results get cached in node.js exec.
How can I force rescan or disable caching?

Answer (score 1):

I have found what was causing my problem. From `man iwlist`:

> Triggering scanning is a privileged operation (root only) and normal users can only read left-over scan results.

I was running node.js as limited user and scanning from shell with root.